# How to test if there is a 'object_list' in the context generated for a CBV ListView

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, tdd

I'm trying to write a test which tests if there is an `object_list` in the context passed by a Class Based View `ListView`.

Currently I have the code:

## views.py

```
    class BlogView(ListView):
        model = Post
        template_name = 'core/blog.html'
```

## model.py:

```
    class Post(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
        content = models.TextField()
```

## tests.py

```
    class BlogListViewTests(TestCase):

        def setUp(self):
            self.resp = self.client.get('/blog/')

        def test_has_a_post_list(self):
            self.assertContains(u'post_list', self.resp.context)
```

When I run the test have the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/breno/projects/blog/core/tests.py", line 36, in test_has_a_post_list
          self.assertContains(self.resp.context, 'post_list')
      File "/home/breno/.virtualenvs/blog/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 325, in assertContains
          self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status_code,
     AttributeError: 'ContextList' object has no attribute 'status_code'
```

Printing the `self.resp.context` I saw a Tuble with the key `u'post_list'` inside:

`[[{'False': False, 'None': None, 'True': True}, {u'paginator': None, u'post_list': [], u'object_list': [],...,]]`

What's going wrong with my test? How can I make this test? Ty

Comment: The error is not coming from that assertion (since you have AttributeError, not AssertionError). Please post the full traceback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class BlogListViewTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.resp = self.client.get('/blog/')

    def test_has_a_post_list(self):
        self.assertTrue('post_list' in self.resp.context)
```